# DX9 Memory Leak : Release() return 0 but DestroyObject not called

Tags: graphics, memory-leaks, directx, direct3d, directx-9

1. Two `IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9` objects allocated by the function `FindNextValidTechnique()` are released but not destroyed. In PIX, the status "App Refs" is "0", but the status "Destruction" is "Never".
2. An `IDirect3DIndexBuffer9` object allocated by the application is released but not destroyed. In PIX, the status "App Refs" is "0", but the status "Destruction" is "Never". After I call the function `SetIndices(NULL)`, the memory leak of the index buffer disappears.
3. An `IDirect3DVertexShader9` and an `IDirect3DPixelShader9` object allocated by the function `D3DXCreateEffect()` are released but not destroyed. In PIX, the status "App Refs" is "0", but the status "Destruction" is "Never". However, After I call `SetVertexShader(NULL)` and `SetPixelShader(NULL)`, the memory leak of the two disappear.
4. An `IDirect3DSwapChain9` object allocated with the function `CreateAdditionalSwapChain()` is released but not destroyed. `GetBackBuffer()` is ever called, but the Surface is released later. In PIX, the status "App Refs" of them is "0", but the status "Destruction" of them is "Never".
5. Of cause, the `IDirect3DDevice9` and `IDirect3D9` object are released but not destroyed.

I'v checked the reference counts of all the objects in PIX and application. They are both 0. I don't know why the memory leak still occurs. And I don't think `SetIndices(NULL)` etc. are necessary. Could someone give me some advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Debug D3D DLL's via DirectX Control Panel, turn on "Break on Memory Leaks", you'll see call stack in debug output.